# What does this piece of code in the kernel.h mean?

Tags: linux, list, containers

The below code is from the linux kernel:

```
/**
639  * container_of - cast a member of a structure out to the containing structure
640  * @ptr:    the pointer to the member.
641  * @type:   the type of the container struct this is embedded in.
642  * @member: the name of the member within the struct.
643  *
644  */
645 #define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({          \
646     const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
647     (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
648
```

I fail to understand what it does at line 646-648. I know what these two lines do from the comments above it, but I dont understand the code word by word. Can you explain me this?

Comment: The main trick is that this code will be run at [compile time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time). Of course, in [run time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_time_%28program_lifecycle_phase%29) it would cause to NULL pointer dereference, as you can see in code `((type *)0)->member`. But compiler is smart, and understands that this code can be calculated in compile time, so there will no be NULL pointer dereference. This code just calculates offset (in bytes) of member of structure (`member`) in structure itself (`type`), and then returns structure containing this member.

Comment: [Here is](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html) a great explanation about `container_of` by Greg Kroah-Hartman.

Comment: Hey thanks @SamProtsenko. Is there any place where the macros of the kernel are explained? Could you let me know of a site or link?

Comment: Which exactly macros do you mean? There are plenty of them in kernel. Much of them are very straightforward and easy to understand (with some knowledge in C). Tough ones are usually described in comments right above of them. Eventually it boils down to two things: **1**: Knowing of C and `gcc` tricks and hacks (like `offsetof`, `typeof`, etc). **2**: Kernel code is quite self-explanatory: you can just `grep` kernel sources for macro you are interested in, and tons of usage examples will pop up instantly :) It's not a lot of macros you are gonna use in your day-to-day development though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intent is that given an anonymous pointer, which you know is actually a pointer to some element of a larger structure, calculates the beginning address of that larger structure.

Answer (score 0):

646 -> First create a pointer (__mptr) to the member. First a null-pointer is created. This is needed to find the type of the member (the *type* of the member is not given as an argument!).

647 -> Cast the created pointer (__mptr) to char*. Then find the offset of that member using the 'offsetof' define. Then subtract the offset from the casted __mptr. The cast needst to be done because the result given by offsetof is in bytes. Otherwise the beginning of the container is not correctly calculated (calculation with pointers is based on the pointer type) 
The extra cast to type* on line 647 is needed because the correct type of pointer needs to be returned.